# How to create multiple Volumes of different sizes in same resource block in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My current Terraform is configured to build several AWS volumes which are all of the same size. A couple of our servers now require bigger volumes. Is it possible to create multiple volumes of different size in the same resource block?

Alternatively I'd have to split this block up (1 block per volume size), which would require me to rebuild a lot of my Terraform configuration i.e. in volume attachment section etc. I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

I need the third and fourth volumes in the count to be of a bigger size. Initially I thought to use some conditional logic such as If/Else however I'm not sure how to implement this in terraform. I'm using terraform 0.12.18.

Pseudo-code:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "myvolume" {
  provider          = aws.client
  count             = 5
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  encrypted         = "true"
  size              = if index aws_ebs_volume.myvolume = 2 or 3 then 300GB else 100GB
  type              = "gp2"
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about for_each? create a key-value variable and then iterate over it

Comment: You would want to use an iterator over a map containing the key/value pairs for your different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like below.

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "count" {
  count             = 5
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  size              = contains([2, 3], count.index) ? 300 : 100
  type              = "gp2"
}
```

you can also use `for_each`.

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "for_each" {
  for_each = {
    0 = 100
    1 = 100
    2 = 300
    3 = 300
    4 = 100
  }
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  size              = each.value
  type              = "gp2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both of these work a treat. I ended up going with the For Each as I now require 3 separate Volume sizes so If/Else type logic would not be sufficient. I had a few issues referring to the resources in the volume attachment block due to the For Each using a map which requires a list conversion in my context at least. For anybody else wondering the following can be used in the volume attachment section: ```volume_id = element(values(aws_ebs_volume.myvolume)[*].id,count.index)```

Comment: A different way to write that expression with less punctuation :) is `values(aws_ebs_volume.myvolume)[count.index].id` .

Comment: what is the way to attach all the above volumes to a single ec2 instance?